# Want to install cmake 3.7 in Mac OS X 10.12

Tags: android, macos, cmake, linphone

I want to compile `linphone` for `Android` in my Mac machine.

But when I try to prepare `linphone` to compile, it shows me an error like:

```
jfalexvijay# ./prepare.py
ERROR: You need at leat CMake version 3.7
```

When I try to upgrade cmake, it is giving another warning message like:

```
jfalexvijay$ brew install cmake
Warning: cmake-3.4.3 already installed
Warning: You are using OS X 10.12.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
```

How do I install `cmake 3.7` in `OS X 10.12` ? or is there any other option to compile `linphone` without `cmake 3.7` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly download the latest disk images directly from CMake`s [download page](https://cmake.org/download/).

Currently the link to the latest CMake version for Mac OSX 10.6 or later would be:

https://cmake.org/files/v3.8/cmake-3.8.0-Darwin-x86_64.dmg

Comment: Hi Florian, cmake installation warning says "We do not provide support for this pre-release version. You may encounter build failures or other breakages." Will it really give any issues if I install directly cmake-3.8.0-Darwin-x86_64.dmg ?

Comment: @jfalexvijay Then just take 3.7. Same page a little bit more to  the bottom.

Comment: Looks like it has interface. Do you have any idea to install cmake via terminal ?

Comment: @jfalexvijay You don't need to actually install CMake. You can also use the Zip version and extract it somewhere. It finds everything it needs relative to the CMake executable. This also allows you to have multiple CMake versions on the same PC by giving the absolute path when calling `cmake`.